# VMware no longer works after Ubuntu upgrade to 17.04

Tags: vmware

After upgrading Ubuntu to version 17.04 I could no longer use VMware. It displays this message:

> Before you can run VMWare, several modules must be compiled and loaded
>   into the running kernel. GCC GNU C Compiler version 6.3.0 was not
>   found.

I'm not comfortable yet with Ubuntu but I tried:

```
gcc --version 
gcc (Debian 5.4.1-1) 5.4.1 20160803
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install gcc-6` and it returns this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-6 : Depends: cpp-6 (= 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) but 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-6-dev (= 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I guess correcting this issue of broken packages would allow me to upgrade gcc to version 6.3.0 which is likely to solve my problem.

Is my logic right so far? How do I solve the issue of broken packages in order to upgrade gcc?

Comment: Something's missing, It gives this:

Comment: dpkg: error: need an action option

Comment: Sorry it's `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: I did it + `sudo apt autoremove` but it doesn't change a thing, when i try `sudo apt-get install gcc-6` I got an error message concluded by `you have held broken packages` which seems to cause conflicts.